# How to calculate the minute in DTPICKER vb6

Tags: vb6

I'm creating a payroll system I want to calculate the minute late of Employee using two dtpicker
Dtpicker1 is for time in and Dtpicker2 for Timeout

```
               Private Sub calc_Click()
               oras = DateDiff("n", DTPicker1, DTPicker2)
               Text1.Text = oras
               End sub
```

Comment: Sorry to ask. Are you still using VB6 ?

Comment: Yes sir, Why? I'm practicing vb6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all employees are working the same amount of hours (8 hours/day for example):

```
Private Sub calc_Click()
    Dim iWorkdayHours As Integer
    Dim iMinutesWorked As Integer
    Dim iMinutesLate As Integer

    ' Get the amount of minutes between two dates
    iMinutesWorked = DateDiff("n", DTPicker1, DTPicker2)

    ' Get number of hours employee should have worked
    iWorkdayHours = 8

    iMinutesLate = (iWorkdayHours * 60) - iMinutesWorked

    If iMinutesLate > 0 Then
        Text1.Text = iMinutesLate & " minutes late."
    Else
        Text1.Text = "On time."
    End If

End Sub
```

If employees have different shift lengths, you can update `iWorkdayHours`.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for helping me . have a good day , God bless